# How to center div within col-md-12 in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with centering components within `col-md-12`. For example I have 12 columns with `<h1>` or `<h2>` inside. I want to `<h1>` to be centered.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="naglowek">
        <h1>Something</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to access css class `text-center` or `block-center` to divs, but everytime `<h1>` was floated to the left. I need have this centered and set padding on my own. How can I solve this?

Comment: please show us your css as well

Comment: Maybe add some css? `h1 { text-align: center; }`?

Comment: you want to center it only horizontally? or vertically too!!

Comment: `<div class="col-md-12 text-center">` works for bootstrap, no need to add any style unless you have already some style for `h1`. even if that's the case, you can use `.text-center` for `h1`

Comment: @ShekharPankaj the term "center" means only horizontally, if OP wants it vertically, his question is wrong, he should be using the term "vertically middle"

Comment: It should be center horizontally. The HTML code is like in my first post. I added .text-center for <h1>, 'row', 'col-md-12' - every time <h1> floated to the left.

Comment: its strange, text-center class should work, but it doesn't. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @mrkkr91 can you upload the entire site (including bootstrap files) to any server and give the link here?

Comment: @Lucian Could it be HTML and CSS files in pastebin?

Comment: If you can upload bootstrap files as well. Yes you can link bootstrap.

Comment: @Lucian ok, wait a moment.

Comment: @Lucian, html: http://pastebin.com/RubUCXbW (problem is between 70-74 line and higher where are offset class (it must be centered within 12 columns, I think); CSS - http://pastebin.com/G9hUYCwn

Comment: this is the problem https://i.imgur.com/FNjiCdp.png

Comment: don't use width. let me know if this works

Comment: @Lucian ok, give me a while

Comment: @Lucian thank you, it was simple and works. I have one more thing. div with id 'tlo-1' has background color. How can I control size this bg color? (this was the reason that I used width) Should I stylling this div or child - h1 using padding?

Comment: @Lucian another thing: I changed the navbar columns to col-md-12 and nowhere width property. The navbar is floated to the left. I changed float: none in css and still is problem. Code navbar html -> http://pastebin.com/ZNQ8X60y

Comment: never forget to post css as well

Comment: if the css is the same old one, https://i.imgur.com/JAtsYQV.png this is the problem

Comment: if it works, I have posted answer below, don't forget to mark it the best answer and upvote it so that the post will be marked as solved

Comment: @Lucian I removed media-query and still is a problem for nav-bar. CSS -> http://pastebin.com/CdFXS6Kf

Comment: upload your site somewhere i can see it fully functional so i can inspect the specific element.

Comment: do you know some specific hosting for this? I didnt use yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<div class="col-md-12 text-center">` works for bootstrap, no need to add any style unless you have already some style for `h1`. even if that's the case, you can use `.text-center` for `h1`
seems you are using width in that parent div. don't do that ever if you need content to be 100% width. and as per background, if you need 100% area occupy the background, you can simply use it in the div if not, you better use it with some pseudo classes `:before` or `:after`

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. i have div with id 'tlo-1' and child h1. I have to make background-color for h1 with custom width. Should I stylling background-color for div 'tlo-1' or h1 (with margin-left/right or width?)

Comment: if you don't know how :pseudo class is used, everything is explained here https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Comment: use :pseudo class for `h1` and place it in `absolute position`

Comment: try to do some more research instead of asking every single question. you can get some hints and solutions for the problem which didn't solve with your effort

Comment: I have notice one more thing. I try use pseudoelements, but problem is that background color of h1 or div overlay the h1 text color, when it is in absolute position.

Comment: Hi again. I figured it out by creating two empty columns (col-md-4) on both 'row' sides and one col-md-8 in the middle. And inside middle column I put div with background color and padding.

Comment: couldn't you make it work using z-index? it could have been easier

Answer (score 5):

In **bootstrap 4**

I know it's not the direct answer to this question but it may help someone

to **center the childs horizontally**, use bootstrap-4 class

```
justify-content-center
```

to **center the childs vertically**, use bootstrap-4 class

```
 align-items-center
```

but remember don't forget to use d-flex class with these
it's a bootstrap-4 utility class, like so

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height:100px;">
    <span class="bg-primary">MIDDLE</span>    
</div>
```

> copy and paste this snippet to check how it works

**Note:** make sure to add bootstrap-4 utilities if this code does not work.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Add class="text-center" to div.

```
<div id="naglowek" class="text-center">
    <h1>Something</h1>
</div>
```

text-center class is from bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `text-center` class to the h1.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="naglowek">
        <h1 class="text-center">Something</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```